# How to read and write ID3 tags to an MP3 in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, mp3, id3, id3-tag

Is there a library for reading and writing ID3 tags to an MP3 in C#?

I've actually seen a couple when searching, anybody using any that can be recommended?

Comment: As to refresh the topic, you may use ID3.NET for .NET Core: https://github.com/jcoutch/id3-DotNetCore

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Taglib# is the best. It's direct port of the TagLib C library to C#.

To install TagLib#, run the following command in the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio.

```
PM> Install-Package taglib
```

The NuGet distribution of taglib-sharp can be found at http://nuget.org/packages/taglib.
The official source code repository is at https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp.

Here's an example using the library:

```
TagLib.File file = TagLib.File.Create("mysong.mp3");
String title = file.Tag.Title;
String album = file.Tag.Album;
String length = file.Properties.Duration.ToString();
```

Comment: +1 - I use this for my music apps. I've not had any real issues with the library at all.

Comment: I've had two issues with it: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=605765 https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=605780  but I'm happy with it anyway.

Comment: i also use this library in one of my projects, never had any issues.

Comment: dead links - can someone update?

Comment: I maybe a little bit noob; but: I've got to disagree on: "is the best". TagLib# does not include any documentation nor method comments to use it. Wich in my opinion goes against "is the best". How come a user is supposed to use the API with no help?
i.e: Been trying to get Album art as Image or BitmapImage to pictureBox unsuccessfully. Even copying the code from someone wont work; as tagLib is quite difficult to understand the usage. Perhaps its just me. Also: there is no way to find info on doing it your self programmatically in order to avoid using sad wrapped classes like tagLib.

Answer (score 5):

I've personally used **ID3.Net** from here:

http://id3dotnet.sourceforge.net/

As well as **UltraID3Lib** from here:

http://home.fuse.net/honnert/hundred/

Both did the job well and were easy to use from an API standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sourceforge project that's been written to do this and seems to have some good reviews:

http://csid3lib.sourceforge.net/

I've only ever read ID3 tags, never written them, so I can't comment specifically on that. However, I believe this project (in a much earlier stage) was what I used to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Also: http://id3tag.codeplex.com/

Comment: Or the project is dead...