# event MediaOpened unable to raised

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to get natural duration of a list of music files which the user selects.

```
    MediaElement getDetails;    //class variable
    private void AddMusictoList(List<music> pMusic)
    {
        getDetails = new MediaElement();  

        getDetails.MediaOpened += getDetails_MediaOpened;
        getDetails.MediaFailed += getDetails_MediaFailed;
        getDetails.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
        Uri path;
        list = new music();
        foreach (music iMusic in pMusic)
        {
            path = new Uri(iMusic.path);
            list = iMusic; 
            getDetails.Source = path;
            getDetails.Play();
        }
    }
    //the function below is not called.why?
    private void getDetails_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hey");
        list.duration = getDetails.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
        MessageBox.Show(list.duration);
        this.musicList.Items.Add(list);
    }


void getDetails_MediaFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Failed");
    }
```

Media Opened function is not being raised. I have debugged the code. The Natural duration after getDetails.Source remains same(i.e set to Automatic) and has no timeSpan. why?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: okay...I will take care next time :)

Comment: Try adding an event handler for the `MediaFailed` event of the `MediaElement`, and see if that gets called.

Comment: @LukeWoodward: I have updated the question. I have added mediaFailed, but nothing happened...no duration and event is still not raised( mediafailed and mediaopened)

Answer (score 3):

The `MediaElement` is not playing the media because it has not been added to the user-interface.  Your `MediaElement` is created in code-behind and stored in a private field; I assume it is never made visible to a user.

I couldn't find anything in the [`MediaElement` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement(v=vs.110).aspx) that states this, but I did find that the media-control did start playing media when I added it to a `Grid`.

However, when the `MediaElement` was added to the UI, the `Opened` event handler was called, but only for the last media file.  This is because the process of loading the media happens in the background, and your code continues running in the meantime.  So, for all media files other than the last, you end up interrupting the `MediaElement` before it finishes loading one file by asking it to load the next file.

To improve things, you can only load one media file at a time, and when each one finishes loading, start the process of loading the next:

```
    // New private field.  This enumerator stores our current position
    // iterating through the media files.
    private IEnumerator<music> files;

    private void AddMusictoList(List<music> pMusic)
    {
        this.files = pMusic.GetEnumerator();
        AddNextMusicFileIfExists();
    }

    // Starts loading the next file, if there is a next one.
    // If there isn't a next one, stops the media element.
    private void AddNextMusicFileIfExists()
    {
        if (this.files.MoveNext())
        {
            music iMusic = this.files.Current;
            Uri path = new Uri(iMusic.path);
            getDetails.Source = path;
            getDetails.Play();
        }
        else
        {
            getDetails.Stop();
        }
    }

    // I've replaced the MessageBoxes in this method with a call to
    // Debug.WriteLine, to prevent you getting spammed with lots of
    // message boxes.
    private void getDetails_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.files.Current.duration = getDetails.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(this.files.Current.duration);
        this.musicList.Items.Add(this.files.Current);
        AddNextMusicFileIfExists();
    }
```

This appears to work, but it is somewhat slow.  It took about 3.8 seconds to run on a set of 35 MP3 files.  This is quite probably because the `MediaElement` is loading in the entire media file and starting to decode some of the data within it, as well as determining the playing time of the file.

An alternative approach is to use the [`MediaPlayer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer(v=vs.110).aspx) class instead of `MediaElement`.  This behaves in much the same way as a `MediaElement` but isn't a control and so cannot be added to XAML.

If you wish to use the `MediaPlayer` instead of the `MediaElement`, you would need to make a few changes to your code:

- you call `player.Open(uri)` instead of `getDetails.Source = uri`,
- the `Opened` and `Failed` event handlers use `EventArgs` as the event argument type, rather than `RoutedEventArgs` and `ExceptionRoutedEventArgs`,
- there's no need to specify a `LoadedBehavior`.

I made these changes and confirmed that the `MediaPlayer` worked in much the same way as I had got the `MediaElement` working, including the same dismal performance.  I suspect that a `MediaElement` is using a `MediaPlayer` under the hood.

If all you really need out of a media file is its playing time, using a `MediaElement` or `MediaPlayer` is not your best option.  Instead, a library such as TagLib# (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1830374/)) can load up the tag metadata (artist, album, title, playing time, etc.) quickly, without needing to read in the whole media file.

**EDIT**: added section about `MediaPlayer`.

**EDIT 2**: normally, it's not a good idea to ask someone on Stack Overflow to write some code for you.  However, in this case, I couldn't find any documentation for TagLib#; only for the TagLib C++ library it is based on.  So I'll make an exception this time.

If you want to use TagLib#, you need to:

- Select the project you want to add TagLib# with in Solution Explorer.
- Open the Package Manager console (Tools > Library Package Manager > Package Manager Console) and type `Install-Package taglib`.  This downloads TagLib# and adds it to your project.
- Add code such as the following to determine track playing times (assuming you have a list of `music` objects in `pMusic`:

  ```
      foreach (music iMusic in pMusic)
      {
          using (TagLib.File file = TagLib.File.Create(iMusic.path))
          {
              System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
                      file.Properties.Duration.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"));
          }
      }
  ```

Here I'm just writing the output to `Debug.WriteLine`.  This took 0.2 seconds to run on the same set of 35 MP3 files previously mentioned, which is considerably faster than using `MediaElement`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I will try this in a day or two.
Actually there are two mediaElements(one currently in use(playing) and other loads the files one by one(if multiple files are selected by user) and get the details of music files and store in List<music>). The problem is that I have debuged the code, and it doesnot calls the function even if there is one element in the list and I have tried this with two mediaElements declared in the xaml like first one(first one runs fine)

Comment: @SaadAbdullah: another option is the `MediaPlayer` class (see my edited answer above).  That isn't a control and can't be added to the UI, and it appears to work.  However, it still has the same dismal performance as `MediaElement`.  Try it if you wish, but I still recommend TagLib#.

Comment: Thanks Luke for your reply, I have tried MediaPlayer, and I found mediaElement much better. and could you please interpret TagLib?

Comment: @SaadAbdullah: I've added a section on TagLib# to my answer.