# Google TTS speech issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I am trying to get Google TTS speech to work, because Windows RT/Metro does not contain a definition for System.Speech. The code below compiles with no errors, but there is nothing being spoken. I have debugged and checked whether 'ListBox.SelectedItem' contains text, and it does.

Libraries called:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using System.Net.Http;
```

This is how I'm calling myMediaElement:

```
MediaElement myMediaElement = new MediaElement();
```

This is what I am trying to do:

```
private void RepeatWord_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string pathx = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=" + ListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    myMediaElement.Source = new Uri(pathx, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    myMediaElement.Play();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are creating the `MediaElement` in code. Make sure it's added to the UI. It won't play if it's just referenced by a private field. Then you can either set `LoadedBehavior` to "Play" (no need to call `Play()` then), or you need to wait for the media to load before calling `Play()`. For testing I just used `Thread.Sleep()` but I would expect that there is a callback for this.

And last but not least: the Uri constructor handles most of the url encoding for you, but in case you want Google hear saying "drag & drop" you need to take care of the ampersand character yourself.

Credits: these posts helped me finding this answer and may have further information for you:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/4baec4b9-451e-4727-a182-555bc312b0bb/using-mediaelement-from-external-source-

[event MediaOpened unable to raised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857110/event-mediaopened-unable-to-raised)

Comment: Thanks. I added it to the UI, and added code to add it as a child to the grid. `MainGrid.Children.Add(myMediaElement)` and it worked.