# C# ListBox copy to Folder

Tags: c#, foreach, listbox

I'm a newbish C#er and here's my question:

**What I want:**
Copy mp3 files of the same Artist into the same Folder.
e.G. Nirvana - Song 1 & Nirvana - Song 2 into Folder "Nirvana".

**What I've been doing so far:**
Read ParantDirectory and List the ingredients into a Listbox. The Listbox shows only the Artist (of course its filtered(Substring(indexof"-"))). After the files have been read my tool create a Folder with the Artist name.

And there I'm struggling!
I need a snippet that copy all content of Nirvana* to the Nirvana Folder.

I really hope you girls and guys understand what I'm trying to do...
**Thank you in advance!**

Greetings from Germany, 
ceteus

edit:"here's my code"

```
void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        DirectoryInfo ParentDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\A7024985\Desktop\_xxx");
        label1.Text = ParentDirectory.ToString();

        foreach (FileInfo f in ParentDirectory.GetFiles())
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(f.Name.Substring(0,f.Name.IndexOf("-"))); //nur den Dateinamen anzeigen in Listbox1
            //listBox1.Items.Add(f.Name);
        }

        // DOPPELTE DATEIEN LÖSCHEN in LISTBOX
        string[] temp = new string[listBox1.Items.Count];
        ArrayList newList = new ArrayList();

        for(int i = 0; i< listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            temp[i] = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
        }

        foreach(string ts in temp)
        {
            if(!newList.Contains(ts))
            {
                newList.Add(ts);
            }
        }

        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        foreach(string ns in newList)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(ns.ToString());
        }

        foreach(var listboxitem in listBox1.Items)
        {
            string pfad = label1.Text + "\\" + listboxitem.ToString();
            //DirectoryInfo plop = new DirectoryInfo(name);
            //FileInfo[] nPath = plop.GetFiles();



            try
            {
                bool exists = Directory.Exists(pfad);
                if(!exists)
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(pfad);
                }


            }

            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }


    void Button2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox2.Items.Clear();
        DirectoryInfo ParentDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\A7024985\Desktop\_xxx");

        foreach (FileInfo f in ParentDirectory.GetFiles())
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add(f.Name.Substring(0,f.Name.IndexOf("-")));

        }

        foreach(var listboxitem2 in listBox2.Items)
        {
            string item;
            string umbenannt;

            File.Copy(@ParentDirectory + "\\" + listboxitem2.ToString(), @ParentDirectory + "\\");
            //listBox1.Items.Add(f.Name.Substring(0,f.Name.IndexOf("-")));
        }





    }
}
```

Comment: Well I think I get what you want, but would you be so nice to add your code? Else it would be like fishing in the dark, what exactly you're missing

Comment: you need only the file copy part?

Comment: Assuming these are in `.mp3` format, [you can use a library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/taglib) to get the `ID3` tags of these mp3s, create a collection, and sort them by artists, create folders accordingly and place them there.

Comment: that variation including the 2nd textbox is just a thing I tried...

Comment: I've tried it with a mp3 libary, getting the Artist-Name and create folder, I just need the "copy Nirvana* to Nirvana folder" part

Comment: You realy want to copy the files or just move them?

Comment: I originally wanted to move them, but in case i'll miss my files because of my s*itty code I've chosen to copy them ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have a `List<FileInfo>` containing your files? If so you can go with `File.Copy` like this:

```
void Button2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo ParentDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\A7024985\Desktop\");

    string interpret = f.Name.Substring(0, f.Name.IndexOf("-")).TrimEnd(' ');
    string title = f.Name.Remove(0, interpret.Length+1).TrimStart(' ');
    File.Copy(f.FullName, ParentDirectory
            + interpret 
            + "\\" 
            + title);   //or f.Name
}
```

Copy("C:\Users\A7024985\Desktop\Nirvana-Teen Spirit.mp3" , C:\Users\A7024985\Desktop\Nirvana\Teen Spirit.mp3

Comment: my file is Named Nirvana - come as you are.mp3, will this work for you snippet too?

Comment: So you're files are all named with your Interpret first? - Sorry I'm dump - Sure it will, just messed up the filename in my description

Comment: I've looked up your profile, Hamburg! Greetings from Cologne ;)

Your code works for me :)


Thank you so much for your support! 
Now I'll try to understand what you've send. 

-The f.FullName is the full File Name including the Path?

Comment: Hey ;) Greetings to Kölle ;) Well yeah. FullName is Path + Filename where as Name is just the Filename" itself. For the titlestring you should go +1 at the Remove, else you'd have the - in it aswell. I suggest you add some `.Trim(' ') ` at your title - else you'll have some leeding Whitespaces maybe - added this to the answer

Comment: Grüß' mir die See! 
I've looked all my testfolders up and didn't even find a "whitespace" or a "-" in the names or folders, perfect!

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this is use the `TagLib#` library ([see example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750464/how-to-read-and-write-id3-tags-to-an-mp3-in-c)) to find the ID3 tags (Artist, Song, Album, etc...), and then create a collection of these, and then sort them, and then move them to a new folder based on the Artist.

```
var songList = new List<string>(); //Contains a list of song files. E.g. "Come As You Are.mp3", "Heart Shaped Box.mp3", "Smells Like Teen Spirit.mp3".
var tagLibFiles = new List<TagLib.File>();
tagLibFiles.AddRange(songList.Select(x => new TagLib.File(x));
var nirvanaSongs = tagLibFiles.Where(x => x.Tag.FirstAlbumArtist == "Nirvana").ToList();

foreach(var song in nirvanaSongs)
{
    //Move the file to your Nirvana folder.
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your Snippet, firstly I'll try TripleEEE's method because it's closer to "my code".
But my older project including Taglib is open as well. When I get this working I'll try your code

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing listboxitem.ToString() contains the name of the artist.

Then:

```
var filestomove = ParentDirectory.GetFiles().Where(f=>f.Name.Contains(listboxitem.ToString()));
foreach(var file in filestomove){
    File.Move(file.FullName,pfas+file.Nmae)
}
```