# Obtaining File Information With TagLib

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Old Question: https://hastebin.com/ocatepudag.txt

I am now having an issue relating to getting TagLib up and running. I have installed TagLib via Package Manager Console in Visual Studio 2017, but when I attempt to use "Using TagLib" it fetches an error as can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A2xc.png
NuGet installation page can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSBLh.png and TagLib is installed. I am also unable to call for any TagLib functions.

Comment: Try looking at the format of mp3. Do note that there are many different versions and variations. You should try and use an existing library. The stuff you're looking for is hidden in the meta-data and it is not required to be present for it to be a valid mp3 file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read and write ID3 tags to an MP3 in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750464/how-to-read-and-write-id3-tags-to-an-mp3-in-c) or [View/edit ID3 data for MP3 files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68283/150605).

Comment: @BACON So I have used the NuGet thing to fetch the TagLib, but it's not letting me do "Using TagLib" it's stating: The type or namespace name 'TagLib' could not be found. When I look at my NuGet manager it states that it's installed. I've tried re-installing and restarting, but nothing has worked. Any ideas as to this issue?

Comment: Do not edit an existing question to change it to a new question. Instead ask a new question and close this one if it is answered to your satisfaction.

Comment: Except it's not, I still have no way to do what I had requested in the original question

Comment: I agree that this is now a new question because...well, the nature and text of the question has changed.  However, I will add that when I use the NuGet GUI to install the `taglib` package into a new console project, a reference is automatically added to the `taglib-sharp` assembly, which contains and allows me to immediately start using the `TagLib` namespace.